# How to configure pandas.read_sql() when using SQLalchemy models with bind_key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using the following model sqlalchemy ORM (flask-sqlalchemy to be precise) with a table/model Result that is stored in a secondary sqlite database, to bind which the **__bind_key__** mechanism is used. The definition is similar to this (fields omitted):

```
class Result(db.Model):
  __bind_key__ = "result"

  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  result_uid = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, index=True)
  ...
```

It is configured as a bind:

```
  SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "sqlite:///" + SQLITE_PATH
  SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {"result": "sqlite:///" + RESULTS_SQLITE_PATH}
```

When I want to perform a query against result.db with pandas.read_sql() I uses this (tried several other variations):

```
q = Result.query
results = pd.read_sql(q.statement, q.session.get_bind(bind=Result.__bind_key__))
```

However this produces the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse SQLAlchemy URL from string 'result'
```

Calling it with only q.session:

```
results = pd.read_sql(q.statement, q.session)
```

... gives the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

I realize that potentially I could pass the full database path, but I would lose any benefits provided by the session.

**Question:** how to correctly use use pandas.read_sql() with sqlalchemy model classes that have a bind_key to connect to a non-primary database.

I'm using flask-alchemy version: 3.0.5

**Update:** in checking out all the various objects that sqlalchemy offers I noticed that db.engines (SQLAlchemy.engines) is a map of bound engines, from which I can request the appropriate engine and then in turn create a connection, like this:

```
instances = pd.read_sql(q.statement, db.engines[Result.__bind_key__].connect())
```

This works, however I would like to still ensure that this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: What version of flask sqlalchemy are you using?  Did you try just passing `q.session`?

Comment: Thanks for the question - added the details requested to the original question